# pass function into Vue animation done callback

Tags: vue.js, animation, callback, hook

is it possible to pass function inside "done" callback in vue animation

```
enter: function(e, done) {

     element.animate({
         // ...   
     }, duration, done)

}
```

in a way that next "afterEnter" hook will be called ? If I do it jQuery way:

```
enter: function(e, done) {

     element.animate({
         // ...   
     }, duration, function() {
         // do something
     })

}
```

the "afterEnter" javascript hook is not called anymore

Comment: I think it is standart part of Vue https://012.vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html

Comment: I did not know it, i just follow found examples, is it possible it comes from jQuery ? I have it included in my vue project too, but what about returning "done"? Without it, the after javascript hooks are called immediately, not waiting for actual transition to end, also referenced here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: I do not know, I have not installed/included any animation library, just follow some documentation on the internet, but my issue is resolved now, It was pretty simple, thank You for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own stupid question, it was pretty simple, just return it from callback. Documantation just messed me, there is "done" just called at the end of the hook.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

```
    enter: function(e, done) {

         element.animate({
             // ...   
         }, duration, function() {
             // do something
             return done()
         })

    }
```